# PHP pdo from database not loading

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some code where I want to get the sessions that have been active in the last 15 minutes, but my php code has seemed to stopped working, when it works perfectly on mysql query.

```
<?php
require_once '../../other/connection.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `hk_lastseen` >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-900 seconds"))."'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo $row['id'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

As you can see, this code is meant to echo all the user id's that have been active in the last 15 minutes, here is where I update hk_lastseen

```
$sql="UPDATE `data` SET `hk_lastseen` = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "' WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id'] . "'";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

But when I changed the first part of the code, part of the query

from

```
WHERE `hk_lastseen` >=
```

to

```
WHERE `hk_lastseen` <
```

it loads every user?

Comment: I'm sure you did not give this a second chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543021/php-getting-active-sessions

Comment: Please don't double post. If you need to clarify something, edit your other post.